# Where can I get the extra large TVP slabs?

Tags: vegan, soy

It's common to see the [chunks](https://ranibrand.com/products/rani-soya-chunks-nuggets-high-protien-vadi-14oz-400g-all-natural-salt-free-vegan-no-colors-gluten-friendly-non-gmo-indian-origin-meat-alternate-substitute?pr_prod_strat=e5_desc&pr_rec_id=58d109d52&pr_rec_pid=6733308297267&pr_ref_pid=4743992246323&pr_seq=uniform) (or small [TVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textured_vegetable_protein)). They're like maybe 1" in diameter. But I've seen ones there are about 1/2" thick, 2" wide and 3" long (maybe this is after soaked though), that can be bbq'd like little steaks. Any idea where to get these?

Comment: Is it possible you're thinking of [seitan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seitan)?

Comment: What is TVP? I've never heard of it. It would help if you edit your question and explain.

Comment: @Sneftel and GdD TVP is not seitan. It stands for "textured vegetable protein", usually made from soy, and is marketed as a meat substitute for vegetarians or a cheap source of diet protein.

Comment: @rumtscho I know. But I haven’t often seen TVP in that form factor, whereas it’s a usual size for seitan.

Comment: You might be thinking of "Dried frozen tofu" (not freeze dried, note) which this site (which I'm not affliated with and just found in a search for "slab TVP") claims is "a similar home-made product" where TVP as such is not home-makable, practically. Press it, slice it, freeze it, dry it, basically: https://seedtopantryschool.com/how-to-make-homemade-textured-vegetable-protein-tvp/ The size mentioned is very much like typical tofu size.

Answer (score 0):

I can buy locally here in Mexico GN+Vida brand 'Bistek de soja'.
Have also seen in asian markets.

Use chunks and cutlets as search terms.

Found similar on ebay from Thailand.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/255689977023?chn=ps&var=555626549295&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1c7lMdohZSxGysZKSkPJlKQ78&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=21562-222008-2056-1&mkcid=2&itemid=555626549295_255689977023&targetid=295996781749&device=m&mktype=pla&googleloc=1010063&poi=&campaignid=19868683663&mkgroupid=145907810526&rlsatarget=pla-295996781749&abcId=&merchantid=433608882&gad_source=4&gclid=CjwKCAjwnv-vBhBdEiwABCYQA0YLGDEAb71pj6y-40QwVmvYHOb41TmsmfVHlBD7mRZ5M0fTVJZC3RoCUW8QAvD_BwE